# Execution of multiple catch blocks

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [executing multiple catch blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035477/executing-multiple-catch-blocks)

Can multiple catch blocks be executed for a single try statement?How can we handle the catch blocks?Can we create try without catch block??

Comment: What happened when you tried? Do you have Visual Studio installed on your PC? If not I would recommend you start with installing it. Then running it. And then creating a new project where you could try things out and play with C#. Once you encounter some problems while playing with C# code, don't hesitate to come back to StackOverflow, show the code you have written and ask a question about it.

Comment: I am starter in using exceptions,so i want to know more about them.

Comment: Sure, launch Visual Studio, create a new Console application and attempt writing code. Also the MSDN documentation will help you in getting started. The kind of question you asked is easily verifiable by writing a couple of lines of code. Just try it - you will see. The compiler will guide you. You could use the debugger to put breakpoints in your code and step through it at runtime so that you could follow the flow of execution of your program. The point of my comments is that you should really attempt something yourself before asking questions on internet forums.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @DarinDimitrov is trying to say that Stack Overflow (though you got many answers) is not here to teach you how to program. Stack Overflow was originally created for those who have hit a wall with the code in their solution. Honestly more questions like this have been surfacing recently, and people have been getting a lot of rep for them, but Darin is 100% right and this should not even have been asked here. I will remove my answer Darin for integrities sake.

Comment: I think when we want to know ourselves everything it may take alot of time,so asking who already know about certain things can ease our problem and we can save sometime in my opinion.

Comment: @chandra: In this case, and in many *many* cases like it, it would probably take less time to whip up some test code than to ask the question.  Don't be too afraid (or lazy) to try it; hell, i'd trust experimental evidence over anything some random stranger on the internet says anyway.

Answer (score 18):

There can be multiple catch blocks (as said in other answers already), but only the one that first matches the exception type is executed. That means you need to order the catch blocks properly. For example:

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception exp1)
{
    // Block 1
}
catch (IOException exp2)
{
    // Block 2
}
```

Block 2 will never be executed, as block 1 catches every exception (all exception classes are derived from `Exception`).

```
try
{
}
catch (IOException exp1)
{
    // Block 1
}

catch (Exception exp2)
{
    // Block 2
}
```

In this example, block 2 will only be executed if the exception is not an `IOException` or derived from `IOException`. If an `IOException` is thrown, only block 1 will execute, block 2 will not.

Answer (score 4):

- You can have multiple catch blocks associated with a try block,but only a single catch block can ever handle your exception.
- Yes you can have a try block without a catch,but it is mandatory to have a
  finally block

Comment: When a catch block finds the exception the other catch blocks will execute or not?

Comment: you could easily manage the exception and propagate it to another block, even if I really cant get how it could be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can only hit one catch BUT you say:

> Can multiple catch blocks be EXECUTED for a single try statement

Keyword being executed. So, you could try:

```
catch (Exception ex)            
{                
    if (ex is MyException1||
        ex is MyException2)
    {
       //do stuff
    }
    else
    {
       throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have multiple catch blocks with try statement. You start with catching specific exceptions and then in the last block you may catch base `Exception`. Only one of the catch block will handle your exception.

You can have try block without a catch block. try/finally will do.

```
        try
        {
            Console.Write("test");
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (ArithmeticException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

try without catch

```
        try
        {
        }
        finally
        {
        }
```

Comment: What happens to other catch blocks if a catch block handles the exception??

Comment: @chandrasekhar - Nothing.  Only a single catch block will execute.

Answer (score 0):

1 Yes `it's possible to have multiple catch`, one catch for one specific exception

Sample

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    ....
}
catch (OverflowException)
{
    ...
}
```

2 You can have `try` instrction without `catch`

```
try
{
 ...
}
Finally
{
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the second part of your question, you can do either

```
try
{
    stuff...
}
catch(Exception ex){}
```

or

```
try
{
    stuff...
}
finally{}
```

, but you can't do try by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Only one `catch` block will execute, and it will be the `catch` that closely matches the type of the `Exception` that was thrown. 
You can't have a `try` by it self. You need a `try catch (one or more catch block)` or a `try finally` or a `try catch finally`

Answer (score 0):

You can have any number of `catch` block for a single try..catch statement.

But please remeber one thing, that your

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
```

Should be the last catch block, since all exceptions inherits the the class Exception.